# div size increases after drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my jsfiddle: [My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/4x0nnkap/)

After I drag and drop the "rule/event" class to "layout" class, I want the size of "rule/event" to be the same as in "rule-body/event-body" class.

It is multiplying in size when dropped into the "layout" class.

Is it because "rule-body/event-body" and "layout" classes have heights in different percentages(%)?

```
.rule-body, .event-body{    
    height: 85%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.layout{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ececec;
}
```

What is the fix for this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `height: 8%; width: 50%;` those rules are related to the parent height/width, after drag and drop the parent changed, therefore, you have a different result of height/width.

Use fixed `width/height` or use `vw/vh`

Solution:  https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/0tdnmghr/

```
.rule{
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.event {
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much :)

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra no prob, glad to help

Comment: After dropping rule/event components, if i resize my window, the components will be outside the layout, how to correct this? How do I make it responsive?

Comment: Sure, one last thing that, when I drag and drop it into layout, the components are getting placed somewhere in the middle of the layout. why doesnt the drop happen where I have dragged it for(curser/pointer position)?

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra I could only think of using vw/vh like: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/6fqaqmb1/, the idea solution should be cloned element should follow the height and width you have inside the left side box (using js to update on window resize)

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra haven't used the drag/drop lib so I'm not sure =D

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra responsive width also messes up with the package you are using, the right dot will shift if the width changed. add another question post and tag the specific package you are using, pretty sure someone will answer you problem